# Include and group JSON by parent model

Tags: ruby, json, api, ruby-on-rails-4, group-by

I am currently calling an API to get a publisher's Books. I am then grouping each book into different their respective story Arcs. Everything works great and I am able to retrieve the JSON in my app.

But, I'd like to change my current JSON response and remove the JSON root arcs:

**Does anyone know how I can remove the JSON root and specify which book attributes I want?**

Also, would a :has many => through association help simplify this and group things how i want?

This is my code.

**Models**

```
class Publisher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end

class Arc < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :arc
  belongs_to :book
end
```

**Current Json**

```
{
  "arcs": [
    {
     "books": [
       {
        "arc_id": 1,
        "created_at":"2014-12-27T20:54:46.518Z",
        "id": 311,
        "publisher_id": 7,
        "updated_at":"2015-06-04T20:55:28.190Z"
       }
     ],
     "id": 1,
     "name": "One-Shot"
   }
  ]
}
```

**How can I change it to this?**

```
[
  {
     "books": [
       {
        "arc_id": 1,
        "id": 311,
        "publisher_id": 7
       }
     ],
     "id": 1,
     "name": "One-Shot"
  }
]
```

Controller

```
  def index
    @publisher = Publisher.find(params[:publisher_id])
    @books = @publisher.books.order("positioning")

    @results = {arcs: []}
    @books.group_by(&:arc).each do |arc, books|
      @results[:arcs] << {
        id: arc.id,
        name: arc.name,
        books: books
      }
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @results.to_json }
    end
  end
```

I have also tried using rabl in the link below, but it's not working..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660136/include-group-by-parent-model-json-rabl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just render back without the `arcs` e.g.

```
format.json { render :json => @results[:arcs].to_json }
```

That being said you could also just change the controller method as well to this but you will have to change how the html response handles `@results`:

```
def index
  @publisher = Publisher.find(params[:publisher_id])
  @books = @publisher.books.order("positioning")

  @results = @books.group_by(&:arc).map do |arc, books|
    {  
      id: arc.id,
      name: arc.name,
      books: books
    }
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @results.to_json }
  end
end
```

This will also give you the desired result because `map` in this case will just return an `Array` of the `Hash`es you have designed.